# Is 400 Bad Request an appropriate response when an HTTP POST response doesn't match the form?

Tags: http, post

Is it appropriate to return a 400 Bad Request when:

- the HTTP POST data includes a value for a field that doesn't match any of the allowed options on the form?
- an field marked as "required" on the form is missing?
- a field not on the form is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: YES.

> 6.5.1.  400 Bad Request
>
> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
> a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing).

from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1